# org-pomodoro - extending its function: popup windows and pomo logging

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-clock

I'm using pomodoro method of focus-enhanced time allocation when I work in my tasks. In Emacs (I'm using Windows 10), here comes the org-pomodoro package for org-mode, where I can 'clock-in' an item in an .org file.

What I want is to extend the function in two ways:
1. When the countdown is finished, I want Emacs to send out a system pop-up windows in case the Emacs windows is minimized or not active.
2. I want to log the pomodoro by adding a line to the item in the .org file where I 'clock-in' and potentially with pomodoro count.

I have some knowledge of Lisp but hacking Emacs Lisp (except for the really long .emacs file and tiny code files in load-path I have written).
Where should I begin?

Please give me some ideas and your opinion.
Thanks in advance.